# Angular Universal Starter Cannot find module

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-universal

I am using Angular Universal Starter and I am very new to it. I inherited an existing project so I am trying to run it on my local machine. When I first try to run the project I get this error:

```
ERROR in src/app/auth/authentication.service.ts(5,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../app/globals'.
src/pages/register/register.component.ts(2,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../app/globals'.
```

Okay, so I created a file called globals.ts:

```
export class GlobalsModule {}
```

And so I run my project again and I get this error:

```
src/shared/user/profile-tabs/profile-tabs.component.ts(53,19): error TS2339: Property 'baseUrl' does not exist on type 'typeof "/Users/jsuske/Downloads/paindown_front/src/app/globals"'.
src/shared/user/profile-tabs/profile-tabs.component.ts(61,21): error TS2339: Property 'storageUrl' does not exist on type 'typeof "/Users/jsuske/Downloads/paindown_front/src/app/globals"'.
src/shared/user/profile-tabs/profile-tabs.component.ts(70,29): error TS2339: Property 'imageUserDefault' does not exist on type 'typeof "/Users/jsuske/Downloads/paindown_front/src/app/globals"'.
```

So it appears this file is now missing 3 Properties.

My question is how do I define there 3 Properties (baseUrl, storageUrl and imageUserDefault) and possibly populate them?

Here is a little more information, the globals is imported into a component like so:

```
import * as globals from '../../app/globals';
```

and Property is called like so:

```
source = globals.baseUrl
```

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: It's hard to tell, but probably the previous developper had some king of settings class (AppGlobals) that he did not commit in the source control manager (maybe because it'd be different per developer). You need to create that class with missing properties, but the values you put in these properties will be up to you

Comment: @David What would this class look like with the properties?

Comment: Actually, scrap that, I missed the import part of your question. It's probably just string values that you need to declare

Comment: @David what would the class look like, I’m very new to angular 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file located at `src/app/globals.ts` and export the following constants from that file:

```
export const baseUrl: string = '/your/base/url';
export const storageUrl : string = '/your/storage/url';
export const imageUserDefault: string = '/yourImage.png';
```

The actual values will depend on your needs